# ERROR: cordova build android project error! hybrid aplication toolkit installation

Tags: sapui5, sap-smp

We are installing the HAT during the installation we are getting this error

> ERROR: 
> cordova build android project error! 
> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk 
> JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40 
> The system cannot find the path specified. 
> Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

Please help me

Comment: have you installed android sdk and set environment path?